# Knowing the data size for a specific set of data in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where in I store data for every client we have. So, the column used to know which rows belong to which client is through the client_id column

Now, can I have a way to determine the data size in the table for a specific client_id?

Thanks
Rathi

Comment: Did you means disk/resultset data size or did you simply meant that you want to count records..  Question is not totally clear.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I meant the disk/resultset data size

Comment: @RedDevil's answer should give the disk size, but for the resultset i think you need to write estimating function.. If you want it more preciese you need to reverse engineer a SQL Server client plugin or study the protocol to figure out how large a resultset is protocol wise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.  How much data is occupied by a table?  Well, you can come up with a bunch of different answers:

- Is it the sum of the number of bytes in each row?
- Is it the sum of the number of bytes in each row plus additional header overhead for the row, such as null bits?
- Is it the sum of the sizes of data pages?
- Are indexes included in the calculation?
- If data is compressed, do you want the compressed or uncompressed size?

That is at the *table* level.  It becomes more complicated at the *row* level.  Data pages typically have empty space.  This occupies space for the table but is not assigned to any row.

I'm not sure what you exactly are trying to do.  One idea is to just use `datalength()` on all the columns and add up the actually occupied space.  Another idea is to calculate the total number of pages occupied by the table.  Then allocate this space based on the proportion of rows for each client.  These will give *very* different numbers.  And both are "right".  Or both are "wrong".

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Based on Red Devil's answer below, does the data column produced by sp_spaceused newtablename give me the bytes of data of only the rows and not the table?

Comment: @RathiRao . . . It returns lots of information, including the total amount of space and the total amount of space used by data and by indexes.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Should I  then use the data column as the actual space consumed by the table rows only?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way to check the size for specific ID. But there is a work around for that.

Insert your records for client_id in an empty table and check the space of that table using the command:

```
sp_spaceused newtablename
```

This will give you the output like:

name        rows                  reserved  data    index_size  unused
TEST    18484                   8504 KB 7800 KB 632 KB  72 KB

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to know how many rows are associated with each client, then you can do something fairly simple like this:

```
SELECT client_id, COUNT(client_id) num_of_items 
FROM yourtable 
GROUP BY client_id
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ac9df5ae21a9be70fcb3a616c805444

Comment: ADyson, thank you, I need the data size of a particular client. Not the number of rows

Comment: Please give a precise definition of "data size" then. You mean the number of bytes used to store the data for the all the rows associated to a specific client ID, or something?

Comment: Yes, I meant the number of bytes of data for the rows associated for a particular client_id

Comment: @RathiRao I see. I think you should read Gordon's answer carefully. Due to the way SQL Server's storage system is implemented it is not quite as simple as that.